# want to use only css in my tabs instead of js and query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

Here is a part of code with some divs who can show and hide some content. Actually I'm using some javascript and would like to know if I can use only css for the same result without js part and jquery-2.2.4.min.js ?

Here is an example of what I want in jpg 
[example.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItYvN.jpg)

or a link to [jsfiddle example:](https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/b7h38y61/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.part').hide();
  $('.one').show();
});

$('.button').click(function(event) {
  $('.part').hide();
  var selectedPart = $(this).attr('id');
  var setActivePart = "." + selectedPart;
  $(setActivePart).show();
});
```

```css
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    }

    .all-content{
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
     }


    .button {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0px;
    max-width: 200px;
    background: red;
    }

    .button:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all-content">
    <span class="designername">MY NAME</span>
    <a class="button" id="one">About</a>
    <a class="button" id="two">Video</a>
    <a class="button" id="tree">Interview</a>
    </div>

    <div class="part one">
    Top by Alcer. Pants by Leo & Lin. Headpiece by Atelier Eight. Earrings by Kenneth Jay Lane at Pierre Winters. Chair and Bull Skill by Orient House.
    Top by Alcer. Pants by Leo & Lin. Headpiece by Atelier Eight. Earrings by Kenneth Jay Lane at Pierre Winters. Chair and Bull Skill by Orient House.
    Top by Alcer. Pants by Leo & Lin. Headpiece by Atelier Eight. Earrings by Kenneth Jay Lane at Pierre Winters. Chair and Bull Skill by Orient House.
</div>

    <div class="part two">
    Dress by Kate Sylvester. Headdress by Orient house. Earrings by Kenneth Jay at Pierre Winters.
    </div>

    <div class="part tree">
    Coat, Top and Pants by Modern Mistress. Earrings by Kenneth Jay Lane at Pierre Winters. Boots by Roc Australia.
    </div>
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269432/toggle-button-using-pure-css
It uses some CSS hacks (a hidden check input) to change the state of a "button". Though you're better off doing it in JavaScript.
P.S. drop jQuery, it's outdated and slow, learn vanilla JS for DOM manipulation, or other popular frameworks like React or Vue.

Comment: that's why I want to use only css !! MWR

Comment: My recommendation is to not use CSS for any sort of logic outside of hover, active, checked etc. CSS was made for styling, JavaScript was made for manipulating the styled elements. Toggling a div from a button should be done with JS. It literally takes like 3 lines in vanilla javascript to do that: `button.onclick = () => divToToggle.classList.toggle("hide")`

Comment: logic, my question was just about simplicity, am agree with your logic but was better for me to use only css in this simple part of code, not all the website will use only css !!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden checkbox to do the trick, as discussed in this [link](http://css-workshop.com/css-show-hide-div-without-javascript/).

The only limitation to this approach is that your div to show/hide should be inserted right after its label and checkbox in your HTML.

```css
.content {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: none; /*hiding the ".content" divs initially*/
  /*position the content to the right*/
  width: 75%;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}

/*This selector targets any ".content" div that comes immediately after a checked checkbox*/
.trigger:checked + .content {
  display: inline-block;
}

/*of course, hiding the checkbox:*/
.trigger {
  display: none;
}

label {
  /*position labels to the left*/
  width: 20%;
  position:relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- The trigger label checks/unchecks the hidden checkbox -->
  <label for="about-trigger">About</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="about-trigger" class="trigger"/>
  <div class="content">
    About content
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="video-trigger">Video</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="video-trigger" class="trigger"/>
  <div class="content">
    Video content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is close to what I want but it's really important to have all links in the top left and the content in the same place ( at top right and under links if the content is important. I want something like tabs but the problem with tabs is that the links are in a sidebar with 100% height and I need to have the extra-content under links and not next to them !! hope you understand me

Comment: I've updated my question with an image example. Please you can see that my link section is at top left, and content is in 3 parts, 2 at right and one under with 100% width

Answer (score 0):

For showing something in CSS :

```
.some 
{
    visibility: visible;
}

.some 
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

For clicking actions :

```
.button:active
{
    width: 70px;
    height: 74px;
}
```

Getting some attributes values :

```
.something 
{
    visibility: attr(attribute_name);
}
```

Also you can try Faruk :

```
<style>
    p {
        display: none;
    }

    h1:active+p{
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<h1>Show</h1>
<p>Name</p>
```

Comment: Well, this only solves individual parts of the problem. The problem is, how do you show/hide a div *at the press of a button* in pure CSS?

Comment: Also, `visibility: visible` will indeed hide the div, but it will leave a blank space in its place. To avoid this, `display: none` should be used instead.